# How can I pass the Model from the view to the Controller's HttpPost Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a form that displays addresses for people (most of these people have multiple addresses) the form displays the current address listed and will allow them to update the city name. When I click the save button, the model does not get passed back. Some of this had to be modified so the logic could be simplified so sorry ahead of time if it seems off. When I save the HttpPost actionresult method returns the model as null. What am I doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CANBudgets(int addressId)
    {
        PersonRepository.PersonDetailsModel model = new PersonRepository.PersonDetailsModel();
        model.Addresses= model.Addresses.Where(a => a.Address_Id == addressId).ToList();

        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Address(PersonModel.PersonDetailsModel pplModel)
    {
        return PartialView(pplModel);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
    public class PersonDetailsModel : Person
    {
        public int? Person_Id { get; set; }
        public string Person_First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Person_Last_Name { get; set; }
        public List<AddressDetails> Addresses
        {
            get
            {
                return _entities.SelectAddresses(Person_ID).Select(a => new AddressDetails
                {
                    Address _Id = a.Address _Id
                     ,
                    Address = a.Address 
                     ,
                    State = a.State 
                     ,
                    City = a.City 
                     ,
                    Zip_Code = a.Zip_Code 
                }
                ).ToList();
            }

            set
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using Personnel.ViewModel;
@using Personnel.Repository;
@model  PersonModel.PersonDetailsModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Address", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { pplModel = Model }))
{
    <div class="row can-totals">
        <div class="table-responsive col-md-5">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive address-tbl" id="tblAddrSummary" summary="Address Summary" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="summary-header">
                        <th class="dt-head-center">#</th>
                        <th class="dt-head-center">Person Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{
    int index = 0;
                    }

                    @foreach (var item in Model.Addresses)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="addr-number">@String.Format("{0} - {1}", @item.Address_Id, @item.Address)</td>


                            <td class="addr-city">@Html.TextBox("city", Model.Addresses[index].City, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                        </tr>
                        index++;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

}
```

Comment: Your `Addresses` setter is nonsensical.

Comment: Try removing "new { pplModel = Model }" from the Html.BeginForm.  It's not needed.

Comment: @BigDaddy that didn't help unfortunately. When I debug the parameter said that the function evaluation timed out

Comment: There should be another Address controller method. Where is that?

Comment: @derloopkat I have one, it's a HttpGet. it works just fine

Comment: Your controller is expecting to be called by post and receiving model as parameter. But the first time you call it is by get without model, hence model is null. Typically I have an action method for displaying the form by get and another action for saving the model by post. Both have the same name but parameters and verb are different.

Comment: @derloopkat can you post an example? Are you saying pass the model in the get also? I am initializing the model in the get and sending the partial view the model. Just don't have the model in the parameter

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If the form is for creating a record, fields must be empty first time. If the form is for editing, then you receive an id, get the item from db and pass it to the view (passing model or using viewbag, viewdata, etc). In any case when user press save, you will be running a different action method, the one that receives model by post.

Comment: See this article https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/ Note there are two methods "Create". One is for displaying an empty form for the user to enter data. The second is for saving the form after user clicks save. That makes sense because in the method you need to do different things. The one that receives the model as parameter is going to save. Then user is redirected to default page indicating information was saved.

Comment: @derloopkat on my httpget, I actually need to pass it some data for display purposes though. I will updated with the get

Comment: MVC is not Web Forms...there is no ViewState concept to hold on to data between requests. Your Razor view is generating a plain HTML form. You'll need to add inputs to it so they're submitted when the submit button is clicked. MVC will try to match up the input names with the property names on your model.

Comment: @Spivonious example? there Is a way to pass back the model with the input data as stated above. were doing it in other place in the app but for some reason here it's null.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)). Then change the property to `public List<AddressDetails> Addresses { get; set; }` and remove `new { pplModel = Model })` from `BeginForm()` (which is adding html attributes)

Comment: @masta_coda - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ should help you out.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is not the problem, I have removed the parameter and the foreach actually renders the name value just fine.

Comment: Did you even bother to read the link. It might show the correct values in the view but its utterly pointless because nothing else works (it cannot bind to your model when you submit the form)!